# React + fabric.js

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

I am trying to combine react and fabricjs but I am stuck.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef  } from 'react';
import { fabric } from "fabric";

function App() {

  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setCanvas(initCanvas());
    
  }, []);

  const initCanvas = () => (
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      height: 800,
      width: 800,
      backgroundColor: 'pink' ,
      selection: false,
      renderOnAddRemove: true,
     
    })

  )

    canvas.on("mouse:over", ()=>{
      console.log('hello')
    })


  return (

    <div >
      <canvas id="canvas" />
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is canvas.on as it causes the error 'Uncaught TypeError: canvas.on is not a function'
Please tell me what am I doing wrong here

Comment: during the initial render (before your `useEffect` runs) `canvas` is an empty string (from `useState('')`. I'd recommend attaching the event listeners inside of the `useEffect`, since it will run after the initial render. This also gives you a way to clean up your event listeners by returning a function from the `useEffect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the initial render, your `canvas` variable is set to your initial state, `''` from `useState('')`. It's not until after this that your `useEffect` will run, updating the state value.

Recommendation: Move your event handlers into the useEffect and use a `ref` instead of state for your canvas value. `ref`s have the property of being directly mutable and not requiring a rerender for their new value to be available.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef  } from 'react';
import { fabric } from "fabric";

function App() {

  const canvas = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    canvas.current = initCanvas();

    canvas.current.on("mouse:over", () => {
      console.log('hello')
    });
    
    // destroy fabric on unmount
    return () => {
      canvas.current.dispose();
      canvas.current = null;
    };
  }, []);

  const initCanvas = () => (
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      height: 800,
      width: 800,
      backgroundColor: 'pink' ,
      selection: false,
      renderOnAddRemove: true,
    })
  );

  return (

    <div >
      <canvas ref={canvas} />
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

It's worth noting that if you don't need a reference to the canvas elsewhere in your component, you don't need to use state or a ref and can use a local variable within the `useEffect`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const canvas = initCanvas();
  canvas.on("mouse:over", () => {
    console.log('hello')
  });

  // destroy fabric on unmount
  return () => {
    canvas.dispose();
  };
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Actually the problem is that you trying to call `canvas.on` when it is an empty string in `canvas` (initial state)

Since we are only need to create `fabric.Canvas` once, I would recommend to store instance with `React.useRef`

I created an example for you here:

--> https://codesandbox.io/s/late-cloud-ed5r6q?file=/src/FabricExample.js

Will also show the source of the example component here:

```
import React from "react";
import { fabric } from "fabric";

const FabricExample = () => {
  const fabricRef = React.useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const initFabric = () => {
      fabricRef.current = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current);
    };

    const addRectangle = () => {
      const rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top: 50,
        left: 50,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: "red"
      });

      fabricRef.current.add(rect);
    };

    const disposeFabric = () => {
      fabricRef.current.dispose();
    };

    initFabric();
    addRectangle();

    return () => {
      disposeFabric();
    };
  }, []);

  return <canvas ref={canvasRef} />;
};

export default FabricExample;
```

Comment: Why are you storing the fabric canvas in a ref?

Comment: @LiamPillay
As we need to instantiate a third party app (fabric) inside a react component.
The instance needs to be stored somewhere and not being recreating.
I see no problem to use a React.State instead of a ref - but we need to use a callback to make sure we don't create new instances

"const [fabric] = React.useState(() => new fabric.Canvas())"